# node.js http.IncomingMessage does not fire 'close' event

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

**When does the http.IncomingMessage fire its 'close' event?**

According to the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2) it should occur when the underlaying connection was closed. However, it is never called for the following example code (I made sure it is not caused by keep-alive):

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.shouldKeepAlive = false;
    req.on("end", function() {
        console.log("request end");
    });
    req.on("close", function() {
        console.log("request close");    // Never called
    });
    res.end("Close connection");
});
server.listen(5555);
```

I'm using node.js v0.10.22.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what about trying to abort the request before it's finished? Forgive me if I'm saying bull shit

Comment: you are right, maybe 'close' is fired, when the underlying connection is closed before the response is sent?

Comment: Try it, add some seconds of delay and see what happens

Comment: @gustavohenke It's a good question because the docs http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2 are not explicit about it. This question and answer helped. It would make more sense to have the close event fire anyway, I often leave underlying connections open for efficiency. A more appropriate term would be the 'abort' event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'close' event is fired, when the underlying connection was closed before the response was sent.

Can be tested using the following server code and aborting the request midway through.

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.shouldKeepAlive = false;
    req.on("end", function() {
        console.log("request end");
    });
    req.on("close", function() {
        console.log("request close");    // Called, when connection closed before response sent
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        res.end("Close connection");
    }, 5000); // Wait some time to allow user abort
});
server.listen(5555);
```

Thanks to [gustavohenke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2083599/gustavohenke)!